# Terminate the main thread from an other thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

How to terminate the program from a thread? I want to terminate the whole program if it can not connect to the server and the user clicks on cancel.

```
class Client(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        t = threading.Thread(target = self.connect)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

        def connect(self):
                try:
                    r.connect( "localhost", 28015)
                    self.refresh_objects()
                except r.ReqlDriverError as e:
                    self.db_exception_handler()

        def db_exception_handler(self):
                if(tk.messagebox.askretrycancel('ERROR','ERROR: Unable to connect to the database.')):
                    try:
                        r.connect( "localhost", 28015)
                    except r.ReqlDriverError as e:
                        self.db_exception_handler()
                else:
                    root.destroy() #I want to terminate here the program
                    #I tried: threading.main_thread().destroy() but not working

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("IOT_LPS_Client")
    cln = Client(master=root)
    cln.mainloop()
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest coding a disciplined shutdown wherein the thread notifies the main thread of the need to exit, and the main thread calling `sys.exit`. [note that only in the main thread `sys.exit` will kill the process].

[This blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/27/python-threads-communication-and-stopping) discusses some of the issues and solutions around this. In brief, you can use something like `threading.Event()` to convey the stop signal from any thread to the main thread.